# Digest is not triggered when scope variable is updated in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am using AngularJS and angularFire to show a list of my tasks:

```
<ul ng-repeat="tool in tools">
    <li>{{tool.name}} {{ tool.description}}</li>
</ul>

var toolRef = new Firebase(dbRef + "/tools/" + toolId);
toolRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(angular.toJson(snapshot.val()));
      $scope.tools.push(snapshot.val());
      //$scope.$apply();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oburakevych/5n9mj/11/

Code is very simple: I bind a 'site' object to my Firebase DB. The object contains a list of ID of relevant tools. Then I load every tool in the $scope.tools variable and use ng-repeat to show them in the UI. 
However, every time I push a new entry into my $scope.tools - the DOM is not updated. I have to call $scope.$apply to trigger digest after every push - see commented out line 18 and then it works.

It's really strange since I sow this several times now and only with scope variables bound with angularFire.

Can anyone explain this? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the Firebase `once` method as how it work, but it seems like it is making changes to model outside of Angular context in it's callback and hence you need `$scope.$apply`.

In anuglar services like `$http` ,`$resource`, and `$timeout` internally call `$scope.$apply` so that you don't need to call it on the callback. If the `Firebase` system provides a method replacement for `once` which internally does apply or returns a promise, you can very well skip call to `apply` method again and again.

Comment: Worth noting that if he does need to use $apply it should be $scope.$apply(function() { //do stuff }); ref http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Yes, you're right, the change is outside the angular scope and is being applied by a third-party library.

Answer (score 2):

Because you change the scope outside of AngularJS, you must use $scope.$apply() to inform Angular about the scope changes. That is a common way to handle that. To use the error handling of AngularJS i would wrap the code in a callback function like:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.tools.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As tschiela says, you need to wrap the function. I use $timeout. So...

```
<ul ng-repeat="tool in tools">
    <li>{{tool.name}} {{ tool.description}}</li>
</ul>

var toolRef = new Firebase(dbRef + "/tools/" + toolId);
toolRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      $timeout(function() {
          $scope.tools.push(snapshot.val());
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update scopes when you change them, you need to use the factory `angularFireCollection` of angularFire. Otherwise you are just calling a javascript class wich won't update scopes until `$apply()`.

```
var getTool = function(dbRef,toolId) {
    console.log("Gettingtool ID: " + toolId);
    angularFireCollection(dbRef + "/tools/" + toolId, function(snapshot) {
          console.log(angular.toJson(snapshot.val()));
          $scope.tools.push(snapshot.val());
    });
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5n9mj/12/)